# How to read data form meta tag using PHP

Tags: php, meta-tags

I want to make an search box where data will be matched from the meta tag of an website. 
How can I make this using PHP? 
I just want to colletct the url whose data of meta tag match with the search text.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php)

> Example :-

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```